# Flutter for loop inside wrap widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

The Wrap widget takes a long time to display these children contained in a for loop.

```
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Wrap(
direction: Axis.vertical,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        spacing:8.0,
runAlignment:WrapAlignment.center,
        runSpacing: 8.0,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: [
          for (int i=0;i<
                  listOfWidget.length;
              i++)
            listOfWidget.get(i),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Can you provide more context for what you are doing? What is `listOfWidget`? I'm assuming that despite the name it is not actually a `List` since `List` does not have a method named `get`. Are you trying to display about 3 elements or 3 million elements? How complex is element you are trying to display? Are the elements frequently updated?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `for` loop. You can use this code:

```
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Wrap(
direction: Axis.vertical,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        spacing:8.0,
runAlignment:WrapAlignment.center,
        runSpacing: 8.0,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: [
            ...listOfWidget,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```